# Call a command line which includes both "echo" and "|"

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I tried to use Python to call the command line to execute some files. However, when there is a command line containing both `echo` and `|`, the `subprocess.call` seems not working very well. Like
when I run:

```
echo "perp -t ../data/ReviewTest.text" | ./eva -b ../data/6.binlm
```

I will get what I want.
However, when I try this:

```
import subprocess
e=["echo","\"perp", "-t", "../data/R.text\"", "|", "./eva", "-b", "../data/6.binlm"]
subprocess(e)
```

I will get everything except echo showed in command line like:

```
".prep -t ..data/ReviewTest.text" | ./eva -b ../data/6.binlm
```

It seems that in `subprocess.call()`, when there is an `echo`, everything after it will just be thrown out onto the command line.

I hope there is some solution for me to use `subprocess` when a command contains both `echo` and `|`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might achieve the effect you are looking for (it should reproduce exactly the first command line listed in your question):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> e = 'echo "perp -t ../data/ReviewTest.text | ./eva -b ../data/6.binlm'
>>> subprocess.call(e, shell=True)
```

1. "|" is a shell meta-character, so you need to invoke `subprocess.call` with `shell=True`.
2. In the command line, you are passing the string `"perp -t ../data/ReviewTest.text"` as the first and only argument of `echo`, so you need to pass the same string and not just individual components in the `subprocess.call` argument string.

Comment: Is it possible to do with shell=False?

Comment: @oarthiban no, the shell is required to interpret the pipe meta-character '|'

Answer (score 1):

The pipe `|` is a shell construct meaning that the command needs to be run as input to a shell.  This means setting `shell=True` when `subprocess.call()` is called.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("""echo "perp -t ../data/ReviewTest.text" | ./eva -b ../data/6.binlm""", shell=True)
```

There are notes about using [shell=True](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) in the Python docs.